# Why containValue method of HashMap class is returning False for the below program?

Tags: java, hashmap

Here I am trying to override both equals method as well as hash code method. But containsValue() method throwing False. Even the hashcode overridden class is getting called but i think equals method is not getting properly called. please help me with this.

```
import java.util.*; 

class Test{

    int i;

    Test(int i)
    {
        this.i=i;
    }

    public boolean equals(Test t)
    {
        if(this.i==t.i){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public int hashCode() { //Overriding hashCode class
        int result = 17; 
        result = 37*result + Integer.toString(i).hashCode(); 
        result = 37*result; 
        return result; 
    }
}

class TestCollection13{  
    public static void main(String args[]){  
        HashMap<Integer,Test> hm=new HashMap<Integer,Test>();  
        hm.put(1,new Test(1));  
        hm.put(2,new Test(2));  
        hm.put(3,new Test(1));  
        hm.put(4,new Test(4));  

        for(Map.Entry m:hm.entrySet()){
            Test t2=(Test)m.getValue();
            System.out.println(m.getKey()+" "+t2.hashCode());
        }

        System.out.println(hm.containsValue(new Test(2)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you guyz, but i am facing problem like even if am not overriding the hashCode method, it is returning true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method `public boolean equals(Test t)` does not override `Object.equals(Object)`. You need to update your method signature and check the class type:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return o instanceof Test
            && ((Test)o).i == this.i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) should be defined to take an `Object`, not a `Test`:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other)
```

You could easily detect this by explicitly annotating the method with `@Override` in which case the compiler would detect this bug.

Answer (score 1):

Method `equals()` takes `Object` as a parameter, so in your code you are not overriding `equals()` method but overloading it. So you need to change the incoming parameter to Object. Your method should be something like this:

```
    @Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof Test)) return false;
    Test test = (Test) o;
    return this.i == test.i;
}
```

Also I would add getter and setter for your i member.